# DRY Then and Always in jQuery Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have the following example JS code:

```
function loadData(url, data) {
    return $.get(url, data ? data : {});
}

function example1() {

    showSpinner();

    $.when(loadData('/example1', { hello: 'world' }))
        .then(function (resp) {
            // do something with the data
        })
        .always(function(){
            hideSpinner();
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            handleError(jqXHR);
        });
}

function example2() {

    showSpinner();

    $.when(loadData('/example2', { hello: 'world' }))
        .then(function (resp) {
            // do something with the data
        })
        .then(function () {
            // do something else
        })
        .always(function(){
            hideSpinner();
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            handleError(jqXHR);
        });
}
```

Both `example1()` and `example2()` use the same promise logic and will do something different with the returned data and then always hide the spinner and handle the failures the same (if any). The issue is that I may want to do different things after the data is loaded in each example and have multiple `then's` follow.

However I am having to repeat the `always` and `fail` code. How can I make them more DRY so they are only written once but used in both scenarios (and other examples if need be). *So I can't just move the when into a method and pass a callback as there maybe more than one and in different then`s.* **So this wouldn't work:**

```
function customPromise(load, callback) {

    showSpinner();

    $.when(load)
    .then(function (resp) {
        callback(resp);
    })
    .always(function(){
        hideSpinner();
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        handleError(jqXHR);
    });

}

function example3() {
    customPromise(loadData('/example2', { hello: 'world' }));
}
```

Comment: I haven't thought this through entirely, but perhaps you *can* factor the `when` into a function returning a promise itself, and then call that and chain onto the returned promise, so something like `foobar().then().then()`. There's no law stating that `fail` must come last in the chain.

Comment: Are `example1` and `example2` mutually exclusive? What happens when both of them are executed simultaneously; the one which finishes earlier hides the spinner?

Comment: I don't get it. Why does your proposed `customPromise` function not work? It's exactly the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have successive and unknown number of callbacks, I suggest you move the whole processing to the created function:

```
function handleRequest(url, data, errorCallback) {
    // create promise
    let promise = $.get(url, data ? data : {});

    // if callback functions provided as args, chain them in `then()` calls
    if (arguments.length > 3) {
        let callbacks = Array.slice.call(arguments, 3);
        let fn = (results) => (results);
        let callback;
        for (let i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
            callback = callbacks[i] instanceof Function ? callbacks[i] : fn;
            promise.then(callback);
        }
    }

    // handle static behavior
    promise.always(() => {
        hideSpinner();
    })
    .fail(errorCallback);

    // return the created promise
    return promise;
}
```

You can now use this function as follows:

```
handleRequest(
    '/example',
    {},
    (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
        handleError(jqXHR);
    },
    (resp) => {
        // do something with the data
    },
    () => {
        // do something else
    }
);
```

Comment: did you miss the `arguments` as a param in your `handleRequest`?

Comment: `arguments` is a given variable inside every JS function. You can learn about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Comment: Cool never knew about `arguments` like that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you *can* factor the `.when()` out into a function returning a promise itself, then call that and chain onto the returned promise with `.then()`, so something like foobar().then().then(). There's no law stating that `always` or `fail` must come last in the chain.

This is a rough sketch for a solution, I have not tested this.

```
function loadData(url, data) {
    return $.get(url, data ? data : {});
}

function wrapWhen(endpoint, data) {

    // return a promise
    return $.when(loadData(endpoint, data))
        .always(function(){
            hideSpinner();
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            handleError(jqXHR);
        });
}

function example1() {

    showSpinner();

    wrapWhen('/example1', {hello: 'world'})
        .then(function (resp) {
            // do something with the data
        });
}

function example2() {

    showSpinner();

    wrapWhen('/example2', {hello: 'world'})
        .then(function (resp) {
            // do something with the data
        })
        .then(function () {
            // do something else
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could think of something like this. Not sure if `loadData` should be held responsible for showing the spinner.

```js
$(function() {
  example1();
  example2();
});

function loadData(url, data) {
  showSpinner();

  return $.get(url, data ? data : {})
    .always(function() {
      hideSpinner();
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      handleError(jqXHR);
    });
}

function example1() {
  $.when(loadData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
      hello: 'world'
    }))
    .then(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp.length + ' lengthed data received');
    });
}

function example2() {
  $.when(loadData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
      hello: 'world'
    }))
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp;
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data.length + ' lengthed data received');
    });
}

function showSpinner() {
  console.log('Showing spinner...');
}

function hideSpinner() {
  console.log('Hiding spinner...');
}

function handleError(xhr) {
  console.error(xhr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah wow didn't realise that the always and fail could be moved like that.

Comment: @Cameron -- as I highlighted in my comment, this will pose a problem when both of `example1` and `example2` are executed simultaneously but one finishes earlier and hides the spinner.